# Digimon-like kids show where a group of kids find their evolveable monster buddies in a cave. One of the antagonists was a cyclops like Mike Wazowski

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Back when I was a kid I used to watch Chinese TV shows on an app I believe was called "Tencent QQ" (it's the one with the penguin icon).
Anywho, I've been looking for this show for a few years now, simply to take some time off and rewatch what I enjoyed when I was younger. It's somewhat vague, but I'll include what I have written in the title as well.

*A group of kids find their chosen evolveable monster buddies in a cave (one could fly). One of the antagonists was a cyclops that looked like Mike Wazowski. In the first episode they use their new monster buddies to fight off a threat (most likely a larger monster) The only other thing I can remember is an arc where they were in a desert and fought off a foe and continued on with their adventure. There was another episode where I believe all of the characters were sleeping/put to sleep and one of the monster buddies had to face-off with the enemy, evolving in the process. **They can devolve just like digimon.*

It is **NOT** anything Digimon, Pokemon, Monster Rancher, Dinosaur king, or Yu-Gi-Oh. It is not anything common for sure. I will thank anyone from the bottom of my heart if they can help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Do you recall how many kids were in the main group, and how many were boys or girls? And can you tell us anything more about what they looked like, particularly in regard to the colour of their hair and clothes?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! 
I can only guess that I watched it in 2012-2014-- it was around when ipads were still a pretty big deal.  Unfortunately I can't remember the exact number of kids, but there were at least 4 and 6 or less. I can't recall anything to do with their appearance, however there was at least 1 girl. Apologies that I can only give this much information, this show feels like a whole dream because of how unknown it is.

Comment: Was the animation 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated)?

Comment: For the most part it was 2D animation. It *may* have had CGI or 3D animation for the monster evolutions like in Digimon.

Comment: Hopefully theres a way to bump this D: